# How to convert list<userdefined> to string in C# where the list is gotten from a mssql database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone-8

In windows phone development I have some data from a MS SQL database. I am sending a list from a database but I want to convert it to a string array in the client. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have, what you want, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# if you have the list then you can try this:

```
string[] str = lst.ToArray();
```

C# List has `ToArray()` inbuilt method.

Here is a code with an assumption that you may want to connect to SQL Server from C#, get the select statement rows into a list and then convert that list to a string array: (Fill up the `?` marks using proper values as per your system/database. [Here is MSDN articles: one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/bh8kx08z.aspx) and [two.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
 using (SqlConnection CONN = new SqlConnection("server=?;database=?;Integrated Security=?"))  {
      //e.g. new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=dbname");
 String queryString = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, CONN);
 DataSet dset = New DataSet(); 
 adapter.Fill(dset, "Customers");

     List<string> lst = new List<string>();
     //iterate through Dataset
     foreach(DataRow row in dset.Tables["Customers"].Rows)
     {
       lst.Add(row["CompanyName"].ToString());
     }
     //to string array
     string[] str = lst.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The tag says [tag:c#]. Why did you post half-VB code? :)

Comment: Sorry I need to modify it :) still learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
// New list here.
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("one");
l.Add("two");
l.Add("three");
l.Add("four");
l.Add("five");

// B.
string[] s = l.ToArray();
```

[Refer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-array)